# How to properly read SQL Server syntax?

Tags: sql, sql-server, syntax, msdn

In the MSDN Library or the Technet website, Microsoft tend to use a pseudo syntax in explaining how to use T-SQL statements with all available options. Here is a sample taking from the Technet page on [UPDATE STATISTICS](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187348.aspx) :

```
UPDATE STATISTICS table_or_indexed_view_name 
    [ 
        { 
            { index_or_statistics__name }
          | ( { index_or_statistics_name } [ ,...n ] ) 
                }
    ] 
    [    WITH 
        [ 
            FULLSCAN 
            | SAMPLE number { PERCENT | ROWS } 
            | RESAMPLE 
            | <update_stats_stream_option> [ ,...n ]
        ] 
        [ [ , ] [ ALL | COLUMNS | INDEX ] 
        [ [ , ] NORECOMPUTE ] 
    ] ;

<update_stats_stream_option> ::=
    [ STATS_STREAM = stats_stream ]
    [ ROWCOUNT = numeric_constant ]
    [ PAGECOUNT = numeric_contant ]
```

How to properly read such description and quickly figure out what is required and what is optional and a clean way to write your query?

Comment: Everything in square bracket [ ] is optional

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should refer to this [Transact-SQL Syntax Conventions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177563.aspx)

The first table in that article explains pretty much everything.

In your example we can see the following:

```
UPDATE STATISTICS table_or_indexed_view_name
```

UPDATE STATISTICS is the keyword used
table_or_indexed_view_name is the name of the table or the view to update statistics for

```
[ 
    { 
        { index_or_statistics__name }
      | ( { index_or_statistics_name } [ ,...n ] ) 
            }
]
```

This is optional `[]`, but if supplied, you have to put a statistic name `{index_or_statistics__name}`, or `|` a list of statistic names separated by commas `{ index_or_statistics_name } [ ,...n ]`

```
[    WITH 
    [ 
        FULLSCAN 
        | SAMPLE number { PERCENT | ROWS } 
        | RESAMPLE 
        | <update_stats_stream_option> [ ,...n ]
    ] 
    [ [ , ] [ ALL | COLUMNS | INDEX ] 
    [ [ , ] NORECOMPUTE ] 
] ;
```

This is optional too `[]`. If used then you must begin with a `WITH` and you have 4 options that you must choose from.
Your options are

1. `FULLSCAN`
2. `SAMPLE number { PERCENT | ROWS }`, where you have to define the `number` and you must choose from `PERCENT` or `|` `ROWS`
3. `RESAMPLE`
4. ` [ ,...n ]' which is a list separated by commas

Then you have to choose either `ALL`, `COLUMNS` or `INDEX` and preside that with a comma if you have used the `WITH`.

Lastly you have another option to use the `NORECOMPUTE` and put a comma before it if you have used any other option before it.

```
<update_stats_stream_option> ::=
[ STATS_STREAM = stats_stream ]
[ ROWCOUNT = numeric_constant ]
[ PAGECOUNT = numeric_contant ]
```

These are the list of predefined options you may use where `<update_stats_stream_option>` is used before (in 4).

Answer (score 3):

Any thing between Square Brackets `[...]` are Optional

Any thing seperated by the pipe `|` symbol is a one or the other option.

In your above example, you could read it as

```
 UPDATE STATISTICS table_or_indexed_view_name 
 [ optionally specify an index as well]
 [ optionally specify options using **WITH**

      If you use WITH then you can follow it with one of the following keywords
      FULLSCAN 
        OR SAMPLE number { PERCENT | ROWS } 
        OR RESAMPLE 
 ].. and so on
```